# Що означає слово "п’ятрини"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Натрапила на доволі цікаве слово **"п’ятрини"**. Однак справа у тому, що значення його немає ніде, в тому числі і в [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/P.jatryny), лише знайшла саму орфографію на [Порталі української мови та культури Словник.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BF'%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8) із зазначенням, що:

> **п'ятрини** - іменник, множина рід, неістота, тільки множина.

То що ж означає це слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загалом [відповідь](/a/4645/585) є правильною, але, гадаю, лїпшого також додати детальнїше означіння.

Як бачно, згадують ся якісь *готові посуди* та *гончара*. Я від’знайшов [Українське народне гончарство і його термінологія](http://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar?q=cache:ORqdCqAVbswJ:scholar.google.com) (Щербина Е.Б., ст.викладач кафедри українознавства; Миргородська Н.В., аспірант):

> *П’ятра* (*п’ятрини*) — стелажі з дощок для сушіння глиняного посуду перед [випалюванням](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

Answer (score 2):

У [Словнику української мови за ред.. Б. Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/50363-pjatryny.html) знаходимо:

> **П'ятрини**, -ри́н, ж. мн. У горшечника: полки, на которыхъ ставится готовая посуда. Черк. у.

У [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/149286/%D0%BF%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8) знаходимо:

> **п'ятрини**
>   див. *п'ятра*.

За посиланням знаходимо:

> **п'ятра**
>   -тер, п'я́трини, -ин, мн., діал.
>   Полиці, що на них гончар ставить готовий посуд.